# Change content Meta Tags for Facebook in PrestaShop 1.7

Tags: php, facebook, prestashop, facebook-php-sdk, meta

I am currently working on a module and got stuck on a problem. In PrestaShop 1.7 there are some meta tags that are processed by Facebook in case a product URL is shared on the Facebook wall.

```
<meta property="og:type" content="product">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.xyzexample.com/en/evening-dresses/4-16-printed-dress.html">
<meta property="og:title" content="Printed Dress">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Test Shop 17">
<meta property="og:description" content="Printed evening dress with straight sleeves with black thin waist belt and ruffled linings.">
```

I am unable to change the content of these tags on run-time through my module.

I also tried to change the content through JS but Facebook is not parsing the updated value.

Any kind of help on this is highly appreciated.